# Error: Could not create directory

Tags: drupal, 4.7

I have copied a drupal codebase, drupal database, and civicrm database and moved them to a new server. I am using version 4.7.0 of civicrm. My copied site throws this error:

> Error: Could not create directory: /home/abc. If you have moved an
>   existing CiviCRM installation from one location or server to another
>   there are several steps you will need to follow. They are detailed on
>   this CiviCRM wiki page - (learn more...). A fix for the specific
>   problem that caused this error message to be displayed is to set the
>   value of the config_backend column in the civicrm_domain table to
>   NULL. However we strongly recommend that you review and follow all the
>   steps in that document.

This folder does not exist on my server, nor do I want it to. It is a reference to a location on the server from which I made the copy.

- I have looked in civicrm_domain, config_backend does not exist
- I have emptied all the cache tables in the civi database
- I have emptied all the cache tables in the drupal database
- I have updated settings.php ('home/abc' is not present anymore)
- I have updated civicrm.settings.php ('home/abc' is not present anymore)
- I have removed/removed all files from the following:

  1. /sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/*
  2. /sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/Config.IDS.ini
  3. /sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/*

When I run `grep -R "/home/abc" *` from my doc root, no matches are found. When I search for the string "/home/abc", in both databases, I get no matches.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: check directory permissions, try chown -R www-data  /site-driectory

Comment: Clear your template directory and then check.

Comment: Can you get as far as logging in and going to the following screens: civicrm/admin/setting/path and civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend There are several paths in there that may need to be changed.

Comment: No, a white screen with the error message described.

Comment: Did you manage to search in your DB just for the "abc" folder as /home will be picked from the setting file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **General tip**: When I've had problems like this (a mysterious setting/value/datum), one other technique is to search the full database. There's no direct way to do that in MySQL, but you can dump the database to a file (`mysqldump`) and then search that.
2. **Specific tip**: In the Civi database, check table `civicrm_setting`, e.g. `select * from civicrm_setting where value like '%abc%';` Equivalently, in the admin UI, check `Administer => System Settings => Directories` (or its sibling `=> Resource URLs`).
3. **Background**: This may or may not be your problem, but as background/theory.

   - In v4.1-v4.6, directory+URL settings were stored as a mix of absolute and relative paths (but displayed *as if* they were always absolute paths). The problem is that absolute paths kinda suck -- they make the database less portable. Ideally, you want all the settings to be stored as relative paths.
   - In v4.7, the defaults and UI have changed to better encourage relative paths. The key thing is the introduction of *path variables* like `[cms.root]`. For example, the default directories in a new v4.7 installation look like [http://imgur.com/RbMgyn6](https://imgur.com/RbMgyn6)
   - v4.7 is backward-compatible with old settings. If you used an absolute path in v4.6 and upgraded, then it's still an absolute path.
   - If you cannot edit these things in the UI (because an error blocks it), then you can use SQL or `drush cvapi setting.create`. For v4.7, I'd suggest simply deleting the offending setting. (Deleted settings will go back to their defaults in 4.7.)

Comment: Step 2 worked for me. I found 5 references to the folder structure from the original server, in `civicrm_setting`. I was able to change 4 of the paths. Site now loading. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Prem's comment contains a good next step - delete the contents of your `templates_c` folder.  The location in a standard Drupal install is /sites/default/files/civicrm.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this. I've been through everything on this page: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location